# Assigning integer to array results in rubbish

Tags: c, arrays

```
    for (x=1;x<4;x++)
    {
            for (y=1;y<5;y++)
            {
                    if (x==1)
                    {
                            feld[1][y] = y; 
                            printf("Feld gespeichert: %d",&feld[1][y]);             
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            feld[x][y] = 0;
                    }
            }

    }
```

The output is:

```
Feld gespeichert: 915094680Feld gespeichert: 915094684Feld gespeichert: 915094688Feld gespeichert: 915094692S
```

Declaration:

```
int main(void)
{
int x,y,groesse;
int feld[4][5]; // Initialisierung Spielfeld und Schleifenvar
(...)
```

I can't seem to figure out why. The for loop increments y by 1, not 1.321252151252151 or anything, regardless y is an integer. Why am I getting these weird values?

Comment: Also you should begin with `x=0` and `y=0` when you want to run through all array elements.

Comment: With `int feld[4][5];` you are NOT initializing the array.

Answer (score 5):

You are printing the address, not the value.

Drop the `&`:

```
printf("Feld gespeichert: %d", feld[1][y]);
```

Also, make sure you have all compiler warnings enabled, your code should have yielded at least one warning (the address is not compatible with the `%d` format specifier which expects an `int`).

Comment: This fixed the output, many thanks. Strangely gcc 's warnings are enabled and yet I received none.